# Android Studio deploy debug version

Tags: android

I prepare debug/AndroidManifest.xml with Mock Location permission and now i want to build and deploy version with that manifest insteed of realese version

i set gradle build to

```
buildTypes {
//        release {
//            minifyEnabled false
//            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
//        }
    debug {
        debuggable true
    }
}
```

but i still get error when launch app

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.SecurityException: The Settings.Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION system setting is not enabled.
```

Comment: It sounds like if you haven't enabled the mock location on your device.

Comment: true, forget about that

Answer (score 1):

This error has nothing to do with deploying the debuggable version. What this error is telling you is that you are trying to use mock locations in your app, but you have not enabled the mock locations developer option.

To enable this option, go to your phone's settings, go to developer options, then locate and turn on the "Allow mock locations" checkbox (then make sure you aren't using mock locations in the release version).

To actually answer your question- Android Studio has a "Build Variants" tab in the lower left corner that you can open (see below). In this pane, you can select your build variant for each module.

[image]

Comment: true, forget about that option, also thankd for show that tab